# MLK as holiday in USFederalHolidayCalendar

Tags: pandas

```
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

BDAY_US = CustomBusinessDay(calender=USFederalHolidayCalendar())

bus_dates =pd.date_range(start=dt.datetime(2015,1,1), end=dt.datetime(2015,1,20), freq=BDAY_US)
```

bus_dates includes MLK day which was 19th of January 2015, even tough there is a rule in USFederalHolidayCalendar about this particular holiday. I want to exclude this day. When I look at

```
USFederalHoldaiCalendar.rules
```

It has:

```
Holiday: Dr. Martin Luther King Jr. 
(month=1, day=1, offset=<DateOffset: kwds={'weekday': MO(+3)}>)
```

It has this line regarding this holiday but maybe this needs to be adjusted.

Comment: Is there a question here? Or just a comment that something should change?

Comment: I don't understand why BDAY_US has MLK day in it. I don't understand the behaviour of date_range function. Why is MLK day included in the output?

Answer (score 0):

This was a result of a typo.

```
BDAY_US = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())
```

Is the correct version and the resulting series of business days don't have MLK in it which is what I wanted.